# definições de classe não se aplicam no css

Tags: html, css

estou fazendo um projeto onde estou criando vários estilos de botões diferentes, criei botões com nomes de classe como "button-default", "button-default-empty".
O problema é que não consigo fazer com que o css da primeira classe seja aplicado nas demais, também não consigo alterar a propriedade a:hover dessas classes.

```css
.button-default{
    background-color: #49bf9d;
    border: 2px solid #49bf9d;
    color: white;
    padding: .75em 1.5em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: .9em;
}

.button-default-empty{
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #efefef;
    color: inherit;
}

.button-default-empty a:hover{
    color:#49bf9d;
    background-color: #49bf9d; 

}
```

```html
  <label for="nome">Nome</label>
  <textarea name="mensagem" id="mensagem"></textarea>    
  <input class="button-default" type="submit" value="Enviar">
  <a href="#" title="limpar" class="button-default-empty">Limpar</a>
```

Comment: Você precisa especificar melhor seu problema, o estilo está sendo aplicado corretamente. O seu `hover` não está funcionando porque o correto seria: `.button-default-empty:hover`.

Comment: na verdade estou fazendo um curso de font-end e nesse curso o professor criou essas 2 classes, a diferença no porjeto dele a segunda classe herdou todas as definições da primeira só alterando o que foi adicionado na segunda classe, tentei fazer da mesma forma mas como pode ver não funcionou

Answer (score 0):

> "*- não consigo fazer com que o css da primeira classe seja aplicado nas demais*"

Isso tá meio confuso. Se você quer que um elemento seja estilizado "com as duas classes", basta definir as duas classes no elemento:

```css
.button-default{
    background-color: #49bf9d;
    border: 2px solid #49bf9d;
    color: white;
    padding: .75em 1.5em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: .9em;
}

.button-default-empty{
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #efefef;
    color: inherit;
}
```

```html
        <input class="button-default" type="submit" value="button-default">
        <input class="button-default-empty" type="submit" value="button-default-empty">
        <input class="button-default button-default-empty" type="submit" value="button-default + button-default-empty">
```

---

> "*- não consigo alterar a propriedade a:hover dessas classes*"

Basta adicionar o `:hover` direto na classe:

```css
.button-default-empty{
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #efefef;
    color: inherit;
}
.button-default-empty:hover{
    color:#49bf9d;
    background-color: #49bf9d;
}
```

```html
<input class="button-default-empty" type="submit" value="button-default-empty">
```

Repare que em momento algum eu informei a *tag* do elemento. Sendo assim, qualquer elemento que você definir com essas classes serão estilizadas com essas propriedades.

Repare essa declaração:

```
.button-default-empty a:hover {
    color:#49bf9d;
    background-color: #49bf9d;
}
```

Você define que qualquer elemento `a` que seja filho de qualquer elemento com classe `button-default-empty` (não importa o nível) seja estilizado no evento `:hover`. Veja funcionando:

```css
.button-default-empty a:hover {
    color:#49bf9d;
    background-color: #49bf9d;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-default-empty">
    <a href="#">Um link filho da classe button-default-empty</a>
    <div>
        <div>
            <a href="">Um outro link, digamos que, filho da classe button-default-empty</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

> Leitura recomendada: [Seletores CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Seletores_CSS)